# getting the last inserted id from laravel with the create method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get the last inserted id from the Laravel controller that was calling using the following code..

```
$invoiceData = array(
            'client_id'     => $request->get('client'),
            'number'        => $request->get('number'),
            'invoice_date_entry'  => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('invoice_date_entry'))),
            'invoice_date'  => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('invoice_date'))),
            'due_date'      => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('due_date'))),
            'notes'         => $request->get('notes'),
            'terms'         => $request->get('terms'),
            'currency'      => $request->get('currency'),
            'status'        => $request->get('status'),
            'discount'      => $request->get('discount') != '' ? $request->get('discount') : 0
        );
        $invoice = $this->invoice->create($invoiceData);
```

In the above code gets executed, row is inserted in the database but somehow I am not getting the last inserted id,

```
echo $invoice->id;
```

somehow, I am getting  `NULL` as the result,

This is my Model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;


class Invoice extends BaseModel {

    /**
     * Main table primary key
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * @var array
     */

    protected $fillable = ['client_id', 'number', 'invoice_date', 'due_date', 'status', 'discount', 'terms', 'notes', 'currency'];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */

    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */

    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\InvoiceItem');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */

    public function payments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Payment');
    }


}
```

Comment: Please show results of `dd($invoice)`

Answer (score 2):

REF: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

> The `create` method returns the saved model instance:

```
$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

will return the instance of `Flight` Model so you can get `id` like this:

```
$insertedId = $flight->id;
```

So in your scenario, it should be like this:

```
$invoice = Invoice::create($invoiceData);
$insertedId = $invoice->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a model you have already the last element.
Example.

```
$data = array(
        'client_id'     => $request->get('client'),
        'number'        => $request->get('number'),
        'invoice_date_entry'  => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('invoice_date_entry'))),
        'invoice_date'  => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('invoice_date'))),
        'due_date'      => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('due_date'))),
        'notes'         => $request->get('notes'),
        'terms'         => $request->get('terms'),
        'currency'      => $request->get('currency'),
        'status'        => $request->get('status'),
        'discount'      => $request->get('discount') != '' ? $request->get('discount') : 0
    );
$newModel =  Invoice::create($data);
```

You can do `$newModel->id` for get the id of last model created.
If you are inside the model you can call it in static method.

```
self::create($data);
```

So you have to call a static method `Invoice::create($data)` and not `$this->invoice->create($data)`;

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. You should write this instead:

```
    $invoiceData = array(
        'client_id'     => $request->get('client'),
        'number'        => $request->get('number'),
        'invoice_date_entry'  => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('invoice_date_entry'))),
        'invoice_date'  => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('invoice_date'))),
        'due_date'      => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->get('due_date'))),
        'notes'         => $request->get('notes'),
        'terms'         => $request->get('terms'),
        'currency'      => $request->get('currency'),
        'status'        => $request->get('status'),
        'discount'      => $request->get('discount') != '' ? $request->get('discount') : 0
    );

    $invoice = Invoice::create($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the convenient method `insertGetId()`.

```
$last_inserted_id = Invoice::insertGetId($data);
```

This will directly give you the last inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to clean up your code a bit like this. Way more easier to insert records into your tables and saves way more time if you have multiple models.

```
public function createInvoice(CreateInvoiceRequest $request){
    $invoice = new App\Invoice(); // or $invoice = new Invoice();
    foreach($request->except('_token') as $key=>$value){
        if($key == "something"){
            // Mutate $value if required
        } 
        $invoice->setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
    $invoice->save();
    return $invoice->id; // this is the id you need
}
```